# Automapper returning an empty collection, I want a null

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

```
public class Person
{
   Name { get; set; }
   IEnumerable<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class PersonModel
{
   Name { get; set; }
   IEnumerable<AddressModel> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

If I map `Person` to `PersonModel` like so:

```
Mapper.DynamicMap<Person, PersonModel>(person);
```

If the `Addresses` property on `Person` is null they are mapped on `PersonModel` as an empty `Enumerable` instead of null.

How do I get `PersonModel` to have null `Addresses` instead of an empty `Enumerable`?

Comment: Why `DynamicMap` over `Map`?

Comment: Yes, this is a horrible bug in AutoMapper. What if you have an entity in EF where you are explicitly loading a collection? You decide that you don't need to load the collection and then you save the data after mapping the object from your dto to the EF type clearing out the information forever upon save.

Comment: Not only this but we were using virtual on our collections. Once we switched over to remove all virtual ICollection properties we were hit with massive data loss.

Comment: This is documented behavior. There is an option to allow nulls.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So there are probably several ways you can accomplish this with Automapper, and this is just one:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonMap>()
   .AfterMap( (src, dest) => dest.Addresses = dest.Addresses?.Any() ? dest.Addresses : null );
```

This code uses the new c# `?.` operator for null safety, so you might need to remove that and check for null if you can't use that feature in your code.

Comment: Is this the best way? The most correct way? Also does not allow me to use Mapper.DynamicMap.

Comment: Depends highly on your situation, if you are using Automapper's projection features this doesn't work (or it didn't the last time I used Automapper).  If you are just doing a single model at a time, then this is perfectly acceptable [to me].

Comment: @c0D3l0g1c I asked in a comment on the question why you wanted DynamicMap, is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: Because I have been using dynamic map, which internally does CreateMap, by going with this approach needed to set CreateMap for all objects within Person - lazyness I guess.

Comment: I'm wondering if you even need the `?.` before the `Any()`. If the issue is that `dest.Addresses ` isn't null when we want it to, we don't have to check if it's null. The assumption here is that it *isn't* null

Comment: shouldnt it be src.Addresses?.Any() instead of dest.Addresses?.Any() or am I getting something wrong?
You want to know if the source is null, and if so, keep the destination null

Comment: @flowest the issue is that when `src.Addresses` contains `null` than `dest.Addresses` will become an empty collection and the OP doesn't want that. This solution checks after mapping (`AfterMap`) if `dest.Addresses` contains any elements and if not changes it to `null`. The `?.` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 86):

The simple answer is to use `AllowNullCollections`:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
});
```

or if you use the instance API

```
new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, saved me some time, thank you.

Comment: For me it is only working if it is placed inside my class that extends the Profile AutoMapper class

Comment: Is this not working for anyone else? I've placed the AllowNullCollection=true within the Profile classes , in the Startup MapperConfiguration, and both together. Entity Framework entities that have empty virtual ICollection<MyEntity> are still instantiating the lists in the mapped DTOs. I've tried changing the destination collection to List, IList, Collection, ICollection, IEnumerable, etc. It still instantiates the property when the source is empty.

Answer (score 29):

In addition to setting `AllowNullCollections` in [the mapper configuration initialization](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html#handling-null-collections) (as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48542179/772086)), you have the option to set `AllowNullCollections` in your `Profile` definition, like this:

```
public class MyMapper : Profile
{
    public MyMapper()
    {
        // Null collections will be mapped to null collections instead of empty collections.
        AllowNullCollections = true;

        CreateMap<MySource, MyDestination>();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have multiple profiles should I do this in every profile or should I set this once?

Comment: @Morasiu, if you want all of your profiles to behave the same way, then it might make more sense to do this in the initializer (especially if you expect your profiles to always use the same initializer.) If you want some profiles to behave one way and other profiles to behave another, then you must handle this at the Profile level.

Comment: For me it is only working if it is placed inside my class that extends the Profile AutoMapper class

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative to this is to use a condition, so only map the value when the value is not null.
This may require that the value default to null (as it wont be mapped)

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonModel>()
.ForMember(
    dest => dest.Addresses,
    opt => opt => opt.Condition(source=> source.Addresses!= null));
```

Comment: only not `!= null` but `.Any()`

Comment: @AkmalSalikhov not exactly. `.Any()` will throw an ArgumentNullException when the collection is `null`. Changing it to `?.Any()` won't work either because that will give a compilation error as a nullable bool (`bool?`) cannot be implicitly converted to `bool`.
Beter is to use `source.Addresses?.Any() ?? false`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to define a custom resolver for the property you want this behaviour on.  So something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Address, AddressModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonModel>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Addresses,
        opt => opt.ResolveUsing(person => person.Addresses.Any() ? person.Addresses.Select(Mapper.Map<Address, AddressModel>) : null));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want this as a general rule in your API, you could configure Automapper in the configure services method like this.

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddControllers();
            [...]
            // configure automapping
            services.AddAutoMapper(cfg => cfg.AllowNullCollections = true, typeof(Startup));               
        }
```

Or, in the case of using Automapping in a separate DLL (example: for DTO services), I prefer to use a helper function, so the configuration should be done there too:

```
    public static class MappingHelper
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<IMapper> _lazy = new(() =>
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                // This line ensures that internal properties are also mapped over.
                cfg.ShouldMapProperty = p => p.GetMethod.IsPublic || p.GetMethod.IsAssembly;
                cfg.AddProfile<DomainToRepositoryProfile>();
                cfg.AddProfile<RepositoryToDomainProfile>();
                cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
            });
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            return mapper;
        });

        public static IMapper Mapper => _lazy.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get the AllowNullCollections working with net6 using AutoMapper 12.0.1 and Entity Framework Core 6.0.15 scaffolded entities. The only method that worked was this:

```cs
    internal class UserDtoMapper : Profile
    {
      public UserDtoMapper() 
      {
        CreateMap<User, UserDto>()
          .ForMember(dest => dest.Votes, 
              x => x.Condition(src => src.Votes != null && src.Votes.Any()))
          .ReverseMap();
      }
    }
    
    public partial class User 
    {
      // ... 
      public virtual ICollection<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class UserDto 
    {
      // ...
      public List<VoteDto>? Votes { get; set; }
    }
```